# Figuring out the pixel position of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using jQuery and jQuery ValidationEngine to do some form validation prior to posting.  One of the fields that is being tested is a hidden field, which means the validation message is shown off screen, in case of an error.

I'm using the following code to anchor the message elsewhere on the page, but can't seem to be able to get it to position across different browsers.  FF vs. Chrome/IE.

```
 <form id="myForm">
        <input type="text" id="field1" name="field2" class="validate[required]" data-errormessage-value-missing="You must select your from the dropdown list." data-prompt-position="topRight"/>
        <input type="hidden" class="validate[required]" name="eId" id="eId" size="50" data-errormessage-value-missing="You must select from the dropdown list." data-prompt-position="topRight"/>
        <input type="submit"/>
        <div id="errorMe"/>
 </form>
```

Here is the javascript to position the error:

```
var er = document.getElementById('errorMe');
var eId = document.getElementById('eId');
var erLeft = er.offsetLeft; /* + 25 */
var erTop  = er.offsetTop; /* - 950 */
console.log('pre = ' + eId.getAttribute('data-prompt-position'));
eId.setAttribute('data-prompt-position','topRight:'+erLeft+','+erTop);
console.log('post = ' + eId.getAttribute('data-prompt-position'));
```

Two different sets of results, almost 950px further down from where it should come up in FF and ~200px down in Chrome/IE.  I did not even try Safari.

When that didn't work, I also tried getting the left/top using:

```
function getOffsetRect(elem) {
var box = elem.getBoundingClientRect();

var body = document.body;
var docElem = document.documentElement;

var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || docElem.scrollTop || body.scrollTop;
var scrollLeft = window.pageXOffset || docElem.scrollLeft || body.scrollLeft;

var clientTop = docElem.clientTop || body.clientTop || 0;
var clientLeft = docElem.clientLeft || body.clientLeft || 0;

var top  = box.top +  scrollTop - clientTop;
var left = box.left + scrollLeft - clientLeft;

return { top: Math.round(top), left: Math.round(left) }
```

}

But that resulted in the exact same values.

Thanks.

Comment: You say you use JQuery. Why don't you use jQuery selectors and offset functions?

Comment: I removed a couple of things just for debugging purposes, no difference there.

Comment: OT, but 1) why would you want to validate a hidden field *and* 2) display an error for something which is not visually there? Is there no other way for you to validate that value?

Comment: I'm pulling in active directory listings into a name/email/etc.  The users can override the values after the fact but we have to make sure they've an active account first.  So they have to pick the user from the dropdown list, then can override the values with something else.  The field I'm checking in the DN link.